# Getting error while replacing "NaN" values using 'SimpleImputer'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have tried every way of replacing these values but failed!
I'm performing this on the famous 'Titanic' dataset!
Here's a glimpse of the data:

```
Survived    Pclass  Sex Age SibSp   Fare    Embarked
0   0   3   male    22.0    1   7.2500  S
1   1   1   female  38.0    1   71.2833 C
2   1   3   female  26.0    0   7.9250  S
3   1   1   female  35.0    1   53.1000 S
4   0   3   male    35.0    0   8.0500  S
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
886 0   2   male    27.0    0   13.0000 S
887 1   1   female  19.0    0   30.0000 S
888 0   3   female  NaN 1   23.4500 S
889 1   1   male    26.0    0   30.0000 C
890 0   3   male    32.0    0   7.7500  Q
```

Here's the code(only the imputer part):

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy = 'mean')
imputer.fit(([stats['Age']]))
imputer.transform(stats['Age'])
```

Trying above code gives me this error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
```

Another attempt:

```
stats['Age'].reshape(-1,1)
imputer.fit(stats['Age'])
imputer.transform(stats['Age'])
```

This code gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

Tried this too:

```
imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy = 'mean')
stats['Age'].values.reshape(-1,1)
imputer.fit(stats['Age'])
imputer.transform(stats['Age'])
```

Again got the same error!!!

I have tried by doing other small changes too but still I'm constantly getting different errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is pretty simple, the `transform` function takes 2D matrix. So, all you have to do is put square brackets on `stats["Age"]` when using `transform` just like so:

```
imputer.transform([ stats['Age'] ])
```

Also, I suggest using `fit_transform` instead of using `fit` then `transform`.

Comment: Hey, thanks! it worked! But it is not changing the values! I mean the code didn't gave any error,and in output it showed an array with all the values in which "NaN" values were replaced, but when i look at the array in other cell it shows the same old series, the "NaN" values are not replaced! They are still there!I think the change is not permanent! Even this is also not working: stats['Age']=imputer.transform([ stats['Age'] ])    !

Comment: because `imputer.transfor` doesn't operate **in-place**, you need to assign it to a variable like `y = imputer.transform([ stats['Age'] ])`. Now, `y` won't have any `NaN`.